# WPF Split View with Two ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently design a page with split view capability. I will be having two exactly same scrollviewers where one is displayed upside down. My idea was to allow two user sitting opposite of one another to view the same document comfortably.

Currently I am declaring two ScrollViewer in XAML file and rotate one of it. However, I would like to the scrollviewers to have the same value. So if user A scroll his part, user B will get to the same part as well.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to the ScrollChanged event.  Look at the VerticalOffset property of the one that changed.  Then on the other one, pass that value into the ScrollToVerticalOffset method.